# Getting exception com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not Member! target

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Single hazelcast node is running which means only one hazelcast member.
We are getting below exception once a while. Means say system is continuously running for 10 days and we start receiving this exception on 10th day onward.

Hazelcast version is 3.12.10

The function call which results in this exception:
***return resolveExecutor(task)
.submitToMember(new HazelcastAdapterTask(key, task), cluster.getLocalMember());***

If hazelcast instance is down, then System will throw ***com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!***.

No clues why we are getting *com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not Member! target:*

After restart, everything works fine.

***1. Does anyone know the reason of this?***

***2. For multiple nodes, its understood that the node on which Hazelcast cluster is trying to submit the task is somehow went down. Why this exception when single node is running?***

***3. Any debugging logs we can enable on hazelcast?***

We tried to reproduce the issue, but not able to reproduce this.

Caused by: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.TargetNotMemberException: Not Member! target: [10.232.104.29]:44536, partitionId: -1, operation: com.hazelcast.executor.impl.operations.MemberCallableTaskOperation, service: hz:impl:executorService
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.initInvocationTarget(Invocation.java:307)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.doInvoke(Invocation.java:614)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke0(Invocation.java:592)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:256)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationServiceImpl.invokeOnTarget(OperationServiceImpl.java:326)
at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceProxy.submitToMember(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:319)
at com.hazelcast.executor.impl.ExecutorServiceProxy.submitToMember(ExecutorServiceProxy.java:308)
at com.tpt.atlant.grid.task.hazelcast.HazelcastTaskExecutor.submit(HazelcastTaskExecutor.java:166)
at com.tpt.valuation.ion.service.GenerateUpdateObligationTalkFunctionImpl.delegateTask(GenerateUpdateObligationTalkFunctionImpl.java:98)
at com.tpt.valuation.ion.service.GenerateUpdateObligationTalkFunctionImpl.lambda$generateUpdateObligation$0(GenerateUpdateObligationTalkFunctionImpl.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
at com.iontrading.isf.executors.impl.monitoring.e.run(MonitoredRunnable.java:16)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at ------ submitted from ------.(Unknown Source)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolve(InvocationFuture.java:126)
at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveAndThrowIfException(InvocationFuture.java:79)
... 12 more

**============Update===========================**

I analyzed JVM memory usage.

It's not more than 55%.2 months logs.

Then went through 2-month logs.

An application was started successfully and continuously running for 5-6 days. I observed below in the logs:

***2021-11-04:-***

2021-11-04 14:11:50,566 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.cached.thread-73] WARN  NioChannelOptions (log:46) - The configured tcp receive buffer size conflicts with the value actually being used by the socket and can lead to sub-optimal performance. Configured 1048576 bytes, actual 212992 bytes. On Linux look for kernel parameters 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem' and 'net.core.rmem_max'.This warning will only be shown once.

2021-11-04 14:11:50,566 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.cached.thread-73] WARN  NioChannelOptions (log:46) - The configured tcp receive buffer size conflicts with the value actually being used by the socket and can lead to sub-optimal performance. Configured 1048576 bytes, actual 212992 bytes. On Linux look for kernel parameters 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem' and 'net.core.rmem_max'.This warning will only be shown once.

2021-11-04 14:11:50,609 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=0 is completely lost!
2021-11-04 14:11:50,609 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=0 is completely lost!

2021-11-04 14:11:50,610 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=1 is completely lost!

2021-11-04 14:11:50,610 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=1 is completely lost!

2021-11-04 14:11:50,610 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=2 is completely lost!

***2021-11-18:-***

2021-11-18 19:13:20,434 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.cached.thread-52] WARN  NioChannelOptions (log:46) - The configured tcp receive buffer size conflicts with the value actually being used by the socket and can lead to sub-optimal performance. Configured 1048576 bytes, actual 212992 bytes. On Linux look for kernel parameters 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem' and 'net.core.rmem_max'.This warning will only be shown once.

2021-11-18 19:13:20,434 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.cached.thread-52] WARN  NioChannelOptions (log:46) - The configured tcp receive buffer size conflicts with the value actually being used by the socket and can lead to sub-optimal performance. Configured 1048576 bytes, actual 212992 bytes. On Linux look for kernel parameters 'net.ipv4.tcp_rmem' and 'net.core.rmem_max'.This warning will only be shown once.

2021-11-18 19:13:20,478 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=0 is completely lost!

2021-11-18 19:13:20,478 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=0 is completely lost!

2021-11-18 19:13:20,479 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=1 is completely lost!

2021-11-18 19:13:20,479 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=1 is completely lost!

2021-11-18 19:13:20,479 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=2 is completely lost!

2021-11-18 19:13:20,479 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=2 is completely lost!

2021-11-18 19:13:20,479 [hz._hzInstance_1_tpt-valuation_TEST02.migration] WARN  MigrationManager (log:51) - [10.232.104.29]:44536 [tpt-valuation_TEST02] [3.12.10] partitionId=3 is completely lost!

Only a single hazelcast node is running.

***Any specific reason for partition lost when single node is running?***

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking why the submitToMember throws error when the cluster is down (single node cluster in your case)? Also, any particular reason why using cluster.getLocalMember() in submit invocation?

Comment: When cluster is down, then generally we get an exception saying Cluster is not Active or No Active cluster. In which scenario, we will get "Not Member exception" if we have single node cluster.  Why getLocalMember : We have written different type of tasks like cluster wide task, member specific task and other. If task not matches any of those, then we are submitting task to local member. Multi-Node cluster support also exists and at some places we are using that.